# Поиск во вложенном массиве

Tags: php

У меня есть массив состоящий из двух ключей: почта и ID.

Мне нужно сравнить переменную $custommail со всеми ключами mail и вернуть ID-ключ при совпадении почтового ящика.

```html
$mails[] = array( "mail" => 'mail@mail.ru', "ID" => '2' );

$custommail = 'testmail@mail.ru';
```

Я пробовал делать выборку через in_array, но как я понял, она работает только с массивами, в которых есть один ключ.

Подскажите, как решить эту задачу?

Comment: array_key_exists

Comment: возможно array_search нужен

Comment: Надо обойти массив форычем и при нахождении сделать break.

Comment: на будущее, **ключ** массива - это `mail`. И сравнивать его с каким бы то ни было емейлом чуть более чем бесполезно

Answer (score 0):

```
$index = array_search($custommail, array_column($mails, 'mail'));
$id = $mails[$index]['ID'];
```